# Breaking do while looping code properly and averaging the loops (majorly stuck on this) C++

Tags: c++, sum, average, break, do-while

I've scrapped this assignment once already but I've saved the old code so if there's something salvageable from that I'm all ears.

I have a do while loop going right now that will repeat two questions as much as the user inputs and that works totally fine. But I'm lost as to how to add the final numbers together and even more lost as to how to get them to average correctly so I can turn them into a percentage.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    //declare variables
    int n = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    double score = 0.0;
    double total = 0.0;
    double avg = 0.0;
    double scoreTotal = 0.0;
    double totalTotal = 0.0;


    //Prompt user for number of assignments
    cout << "How many assignments are there? ";
    cin >> n;

    counter = 0;
    do
    { 
        counter++;

        //prompt user for score    */count up for each query*/
        cout << "What is the score for assignment number " << counter << "? ";
        cin >> score;

        //prompt user for totals         */count up for each total*/
        cout << "What is the total score available for assignment number " << counter << "? ";
        cin >> total;

    }
    while(counter < n);

    //calculate averages

    scoreTotal += score;
    totalTotal += total;

    avg = ((scoreTotal / totalTotal) * 100) / n; 

    //output how much it was out of and percent

    cout << "Your total is " << scoreTotal << " out of " << totalTotal << ", or " <<  avg << "%" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I just guess on the avg section and it doesn't come out correctly so I know that's wrong.

My old code got it to end the loop cycle correctly but it does majorly whack things to the new code like alter the counter to only even numbers and it outputs one prompt higher than what the user requests.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    float s;  // assignment score
    float t;  // total points worth
    float p;  // percentage     
    int n;

    //input the number of assignments
    cout << "How many assignments are there? ";
    cin >> n;

        for (int i=1; i <=n; i++)
        {
            //input the total points earned for assignment
            cout << "What is the score earned for this assignment? ";
            cin >> s;

            //input the number of points assignment is worth
            cout << "How many points was the assignment worth? ";
            cin >> t;

            //calculate percentage
            p = ((s / t) * 100) ;
            p += i;
        }


    //output score
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);
    cout << "Total score: " << p << "%"<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My textbook isn't helping either. It jumps from explaining Do and Do While loops to showing how to use For loops without any explanation as to the compatibility of them.

Anything helps! Thanks!

Comment: Please explain directly what the assignment is, so we don't need to deduce it from your code.

Comment: I can do you better, I'll copy and paste the parameters.

Comment: Write a program that calculates the total grade for N classroom exercises as a percentage. The user should input the value for N followed by each of the N scores and totals. Calculate the overall percentage (sum of the total points earned divided by the total points possible.) and output it as a percentage. Sample input and output is shown below.
How many exercises to input? 3
Score received for exercise 1: 10 Total points possible for exercise 1: 10
Score received for exercise 2: 7 Total points possible for exercise 2: 12

Your total is 22 out of 30, or 73.33%

Comment: Please edit your question to include this.

Comment: `p += i` what is the meaning of this part? Every loop iteration the values of s, t and p are assigned new values, so the data from the previous iteration is lost.

Comment: That's from the old scrapped code. That explains why my output was only displaying the answer to the final input. I had that in to break the loop on the suggestion of someone on this site in a previous question for this assignment.

Comment: Not sure why you posted C++ code in a Live HTML/JS/CSS demo box?

Comment: I'm REALLY new to this site. I just clicked the "insert code" button on the post.

Comment: Gather input score and total. Divide score by total and multiply by 100. Add this value to a running total, that begins at 0. After your loop, divide the running total by the number of scores.

Comment: Okay that works great thank you. I'm still having an issue where it prompts me one more time than inputted for 'n', and that skews the data completely. I insert a '2' for n and if you check the math incorrectly it works but it's prompting me 3 times and I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: If counter starts at 0, you should use `< n` not `<= n`. Also make sure you have the right type of loop. What happens if someone wants to input 0 entries?

Comment: Yeah I would just need a while loop for that, wouldn't I? I thought about the fact that if I only inputted 0 it wouldn't work right. I might go through and alter that later. This is due at midnight so I've been more concerned with getting it done. I've been working on this for 3 days and it's kicking my ass.

Comment: A for or while loop check the condition at the beginning, a do-while loop at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a little messy but I kind of got the gist of your assignment.

According to your title you seem to be looking for the total of X assignments that is inputted by the user. Right now you are only keeping track of the last score and total that the user has inputted.

Eg.
Score = 5, Total = 10   - Next Iteration
Score = 7, Total = 20   - The 5 and 10 get wiped out.

What you need to do is to keep track of all of them either using an array (Which seems to be beyond your scope) so I would recommend just summing them all up and keeping track of the cumulative score and total. To do so, you just simply need to add

```
scoreTotal += score;
totalTotal += total;  // Terrible name sorry
```

What += means is scoreTotal = score + scoreTotal and it will keep track of the cumulative sum. At the end all you have to do is scoreTotal/totalTotal to find the average.

Comment: Yeah this is our second week of class so we haven't touched arrays yet. Technically we're only on chapter two of the textbook but this sort of work is covered in chapter three and we didn't go over it in depth in class which is why I'm struggling so much with it. What you wrote is really similar to the code I had going before. I'll give it a go!

Comment: So I inputted what you suggested and combined it with the tip Neil Kirk suggested for finding the average but the shell I'm using (cpp.sh) is warning me that scoreTotal and totalTotal aren't initialized in that function. My googling around isn't solving that problem either. '//calculate averages
    
    scoreTotal += score;
    totalTotal += total;
    
    avg = ((scoreTotal / totalTotal) * 100) / n; '

Comment: You need to declare float scoreTotal = 0; and float totalTotal = 0; before the loop

Comment: You don't need an array for this - it would use unnecessary space.

Comment: If you declare a variable of basic type (int, float, etc) without an initial value, it is an error to read it until you have written a value.

Comment: That's completely up to the programmer.

Comment: @NeilKirk actually, since this is C++, you just get a random number in your variable and not an error.

Comment: I'm sorry my statement was not clear. I didn't mean an error is reported to you, just that to do so is an error.

Comment: My average is coming out incorrectly at the moment and I can't pinpoint the error. If I input a score of 5/10 total and 10/10, I should get 75%. Instead I get 50%. Same if I reverse the input. If I SOMETIMES get correct answers but I'm almost positive it's coincidence.

Comment: Can you update your question with what your code looks like now?

Comment: Only the code between `do {` and `} while(..)` is executed each time in the loop. Any code outside of that will not be executed each time.

Comment: Alright I moved the `} while...` below my average and solved the math issue by removing `/ n` from the equation. That was giving me the bad math that resulted from the correction. My assignment works perfectly now. Thank you both! You saved me from a frustrated and unfruitful all nighter. I'm going to clean this code up majorly and submit it.

Answer (score 0):

Final Code looks like:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    //declare variables
    int n, counter;
    double score, total, scoreSum = 0, totalSum = 0, answer;


    //Prompt user for number of assignments
    cout << "How many exercises to input? ";
    cin >> n;

    counter = 0;
    do
        { 
        counter++;

        //prompt user for score    */count up for each query*/

        cout << "What is the score for exercise " << counter << "? ";
        cin >> score;

        //prompt user for totals         */count up for each total*/

        cout << "What is the total points possible for exercise " << counter << "? ";
        cin >> total;


        //calculate averages

        scoreSum += score;
        totalSum += total;

        answer = (scoreSum / totalSum) * 100; 

            }
        while ( counter < n);


    //output how much it was out of and percent

    cout << "Your total is " << scoreSum << " out of " << totalSum << ", or " << fixed << setprecision (2) << answer << "%" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to recalculate `answer` every loop iteration unless you are going to do something with the intermediary values.